# How can I get Jelly Bean style text fields using CSS?

Tags: css, border

Check out this screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible, using only css(3), to get a border around a textfield that only wraps partially up each side?

Comment: yes this is possible css3 used to border-bottom or used to after or before in css

Comment: Probably in conjunction with a `background-image`

Comment: Fiddle around for several minutes and it seems that `input[type="text"]` doesn't care about `::before` and `::after`. So I think `background-image` would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the codepen: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FBslm)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text field">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Another one">
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
* {

   box-sizing: border-box;

}


body {

  background: #dfdfdf;

}


input {

  width: 250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  color: #444;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  outlne: none;
  display: block;

}

input:focus {

    outline:none;

}


.wrapper {

  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;

}


.wrapper:before {

  width: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -1px;

}

.wrapper:after {

  width: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;

}

.wrapper:hover::after, .wrapper:hover::before {

    background: #57B8D6;
    width: 2px;

}

.wrapper:hover::after {

    right: 0px;

}

.wrapper:hover::before {

    left: 0px;

}

.wrapper:before {

    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;

}

.wrapper:hover {

    border-bottom: 2px solid #57B8D6;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -125px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted but it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/3hrNp/2/

However, it would probably be better to use a background image - much simpler.

```
<div class="container">       
    <div class="parent">
        <input type="textbox" value="Username or email" />
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="parent">
        <input type="textbox" value="Password" />
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 210px;
    background-color: #F1F0EE;
    padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
    border: none;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 2px #CCCBCA;
    border-top: none;
}

input:focus + div.inner {
    border: solid 2px #57B8D6;
    border-top: none;
}

input {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    color: #6E6F6F;
    background-color: #F1F0EE;
}
```

Comment: this one is better because it changes when you focus it